# Storing Large Amounts of Numbers in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been thinking this problem over for awhile now and have yet to think of a good way to accomplish it, especially with keeping the tables in some sort of normalization and the data manageable.

I have a 33 x 24 grid map, totaling 792 tiles, and each single tile should have an integer value stored with it. Now, it gets slightly more complex since each of those 792 unique map values will contain another 100 values each with small integer values (likely nothing more than two digits), making 79,200 total unique values being stored.

Theoretically there would be a "tblMap" table that would have a unique mapID and 792 related fields per mapID. Then each of those 792 fields would have a table related to them that would have another 100 fields of data.

This is essentially a large 2D tile map that will be displayed to and updated by a user on a website. The data should not be stored locally for users. I'm using MySQL to store the data and PHP to access and manipulate it.

So what would be the best way to store this, whether with MySQL or possibly saving and loading a file with the values? And what would the table structure for something like this be? Is it a bad thing to have 792 rows in a single table (I kind of think so, but don't see any normalization rules about it)?

I hope that is clear and makes some sense. I searched around and was able to find related topics, but nothing that was specific to this type of case.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Watch Matrix 5 MySQL.

Comment: I'm sorry but do you have a link? Searching Google, Youtube and here for "Matrix 5 MySQL" hasn't revealed anything useful.